# How to initialize a subclass when no superclass init fits

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I know this is a silly example, but it's the smallest one I could think of that demonstrates my problems.
Let's say I have a Swift 5 project with some UI Buttons in it. As background, this project doesn't use storyboards, and where possible I don't specify frames for subviews, as everything is positioned with the various `.constraint()` methods. Also, let's say all of my buttons are declared in one of these two ways:

```swift
let yellowButton = UIButton()
yellowButton.setTitleColor(.yellow, for: .normal)

let blueButton = UIButton()
blueButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
```

I decide that I want to compact this, by creating a subclass of `UIButton` that I can construct as `let yellowButton = MyButton(isYellow: true)`, since there are only two colors. I've tried to write something like this:

```swift
import UIKit

class MyButton: UIButton {
  private var isYellow: Bool

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Not using storyboards")
  }

  init(isYellow: Bool) {
    self.isYellow = isYellow
    super.init() // <-- Compile error here
  }

  // ... code to handle color automatically ...
}
```

However, it doesn't let me call `super.init()`. It gives me the options of `super.init(coder:)`, `super.init(frame:)`, `super.init(type:)`, `super.init(frame:primaryAction:)`, and `super.init(type:primaryAction:)`. None of these seem particularly like what I want. Since I'm using constraints to position it, I suppose I could call `init(frame:)` with an arbitrary constant CGRect, but semantically that seems odd. I have two questions about this:

1. Why can I call `UIButton()` in my view controllers, but not `super.init()` in a subclass of UIButton?
2. What's the best way to handle this situation, and more generally, what should I do when none of the superclass's initializers seem appropriate?

Comment: Use `super.init(frame:.zero)`

Comment: @Paulw11 why would using `CGRect.zero` make more sense than, say, `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 48, height: 48)`? A button can't be 0 x 0; 48 x 48 is the recommended minimum size.

Comment: Because it's less to type. The button will be sized by its intrinsic content size and/or constraints. Using `.zero` is the standard approach.

Comment: You have to call the designated initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having calling `super.init()` is because that initializer is actually a `convenience` initializer, and subclasses must call a designated initializer.  Most UIKit/AppKit classes that have both a designated initializer that accepts an `NSRect` and a `convenience` initializer with no parameters simply chain to the designated one with `.zero` for the `NSRect`.  Paulw11's comments allude to this when he suggests calling it explicitly with `.zero`.